# how to call overridden validation method

Tags: spring-mvc

Doing validation for a spring form

```
@Autowired
private TcsManagementEndUserValidator tcsManagementEndUserValidator;

@InitBinder("command")
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(tcsManagementEndUserValidator);
}
```

I have created a validate method in TcsManagementEndUserValidator  file and want to use it in place of old method

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors, boolean allowEmptyPassword,boolean iscustomerInstance)
```

How this method can be called in place of default implementation of validate method

Answer (score 0):

To create `TcsManagementEndUserValidator`, you need to implement `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface and override its methods. Then after setting this validator in initBinder, `validate(Object target, Errors errors)` method will be invoked.

For `boolean allowEmptyPassword,boolean iscustomerInstance`, you can create properties and set values from setter method.

When overriding a method, you can not change its number of parameters.